# Typescript emitted type declaration files not including "undefined" as a type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create some utility functions for a common library to be used in my Typescript projects, with functions like:

`common.ts`:

```
// null, undefined
export const isNull = (value: any): value is null | undefined => value === null || value === undefined;

// null, undefined, []
export const isEmptyArray = (value: unknown[] | null | undefined): value is null | undefined | [] => isNull(value)
|| (Array.isArray(value) && value?.length === 0);
```

and so on. When I emit the type declaration files (.d.ts), I am getting something like this:

`common.d.ts`:

```
export declare const isNull: (value: any) => value is null;
export declare const isEmptyArray: (value: unknown[] | null | undefined) => value is [];
```

This is causing issues with Typescript when I later try to invoke these functions, because Typescript will still believe that a value is possibly `undefined` even after checking `if (!isNull(val)) { ... }`. Typescript correctly deduces the type when I am using `common.ts` in a local project, but it does not when that function is imported from the library. Why are `undefined` (and sometimes `null`) values being omitted in the type declaration files?

For reference, my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "target": "es6",
  "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist/esm",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you want `undefined` and `null` to consistently appear and be distinguished from each other you should turn on the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Well now I feel silly, yes, that was the option I was missing. Setting that to true correctly generates the types. If you add that as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance, maybe in a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) unfortunately do not enable [the recommended `--strict` suite of features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).  One important such feature is [`--strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks).

With `--strictNullChecks` off, the [`null` and `undefined` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) are "absorbed" into other types; the compiler allows you to assign `null` or `undefined` to any variable, even if the variable's type does not mention `null` or `undefined`. Conversely when types are emitted to [declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration), they will tend to suppress `null` and `undefined` when they are present in [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  So `string | undefined` will become just `string`.

With `--strictNullChecks` on, the `null` and `undefined` types are considered to be separate from other types and will not be absorbed into unions.  Since `string | undefined` is distinct from `string`, emitted declaration files will never collapse the former to the latter.

If you want `null` and `undefined` to be checked strictly (and you should), then you should probably enable it... or, even better, enable `--strict` to get the other recommended settings like [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) and [`--strictPropertyInitialization`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization).